# Can SQL Server look ahead into XML tags and/or count them?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<channel id="EPG123.11331.schedulesdirect.org">
    <display-name>WCBS</display-name>
    <display-name>WCBS</display-name>
    <display-name>2 WCBS</display-name>
    <display-name>2</display-name>
    <display-name>CBS</display-name>
    <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201.s3. ... w_270h.png" />
</channel>
```

Note the 5 XML elements all named `display-name`.

Here is the SQL Server code to insert the data:

```
SELECT *
INTO channels
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/tv/channel', 2)
WITH (
      id varchar(50) '@id',
      chan1 varchar(50) 'display-name[1]',
      chan2 varchar(50) 'display-name[2]',
      chan3 varchar(50) 'display-name[3]',
      chan4 float 'display-name[4]',
      chan5 varchar(50) 'display-name[5]',
      icon varchar(100)
)
```

The values of each tag is the same for all occurrences of the `<channel>` element, so use of the data in the database is not affected.

However, here is the XML in a new upgrade:

```
<channel id="EPG123.11331.schedulesdirect.org">
    <display-name>WCBS</display-name>
    <display-name>2 WCBS</display-name>
    <display-name>2</display-name>
    <display-name>CBS</display-name>
    <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201.s3. ... w_270h.png" />
</channel>
```

Note that the 2nd XML element is removed (presumably because it's identical to the 1st one). But when they are different, both elements appear.

So now I can't tell what's in the subsequent elements.

My question is, can SQL Server count the `display-name` elements, or look at and test the data values in the elements?

---

I tried this test and it works:

```
select iif(isnull(null, -1) = -1, 'null', 'not null')
```

But this code:

```
chan2 varchar(50) iif(isnull('display-name[5]', -1) = -1, 'display-name[2]', 'display-name[1]'),
```

Gives a syntax error.

If this can work, then the same format will be used for the columns chan2 through chan5.  E.g, chan3 will be assigned to either index 3 or 2 of display-name, etc.

Suggestions?

---

Regardless of which xml format is encountered (whether there are 4 or 5 display-name elements), the result should look like this:

```
id                                 chan1    chan2   chan3   chan4   chan5
EPG123.11331.schedulesdirect.org   WCBS     WCBS    2 WCBS  2       CBS
```

There will be cases where chan1 is different from chan2.  But I can't tell when that will happen.

---

Here is the code that is causing a syntax error in the INTO clause.

```
     DECLARE @x xml
    SELECT @x = P
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\projects\epg123new.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS tv(P)

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

insert into channels (id, chan1, chan2, chan3, chan4, chan5, icon)
SELECT
      channel.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(50)') id,
      channel.value('(display-name)[1]','varchar(50)') chan1,
      channel.value('(display-name[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then 1 else 2)])[1]','varchar(50)') chan2,
      channel.value('(display-name[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then 2 else 3)])[1]','varchar(50)') chan3 ,
      channel.value('(display-name[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then 3 else 4)])[1]','float') chan4,
      channel.value('(display-name[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then 4 else 5)])[1]', 'varchar(50)') chan5,
      channel.value('(icon/@src)[1]','varchar(100)') icon
INTO channels
FROM @hdoc.nodes('/channel') x(channel)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
go
```

Comment: Yes it can, for example `display-name[text() = "WCBS"][1]` but how do you know what text to look for? Are just looking for all distinct elements?

Comment: You are right.  There are several hundred records.  Each identifying different channels.  What is needed is to test the count of elements, or maybe test that the 5th element exists.  And based on that, an if() statement on which elements are inserted to each column is needed.  Is that possible?

Comment: If you can [edit] and explain fully the exact logic that you need to identify records (bearing in mind whether or not you know beforehand what each node should contain, we could come up with something

Comment: I added text showing code that would do what I want.  If 'display-name[5]' is null, then replicate the first element to the second column, and then use the same code for the next 3 columns to use the appropriate element based on whether there are 4 or 5 elements.  I need to know the proper syntax to be used in the WITH clause.  Or if there is another way to code the solution.

Comment: So basically, the logic is simply "if there are 4 nodes, chan2 is the same as chan1, and all the other nodes are 1 less on their indexers"?

Comment: @Dan, It is not clear what you are after. Please edit your original post and add desired output.

Comment: @Charlieface - Yes exactly.  The iif statement in the last code snippet would be replicated across all remaining columns.  If display-name[5] is not null, use the associated element.  If it is null, use the previous one.

Comment: @Yizhak, I've made the edit on the post with more detail and a sample of the desired output.

Comment: Charlie, Sorry, I didn't see the answer.  I'll let you know.

Comment: If you are using `insert into...select...`, remove the second `into Channels` line and ad beforehand a `create table` statement. Also you don't need `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` if you are using `.nodes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method. Slightly more performant as it calculates number of `<display-name>` elements just once per channel. And eliminates a conditional logic with the `if/else` statement.

All credit goes to @Charlieface. I just optimized his solution.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<tv>
    <channel id="EPG123.11331.schedulesdirect.org">
        <display-name>WCBS</display-name>
        <display-name>WCBS</display-name>
        <display-name>2 WCBS</display-name>
        <display-name>2</display-name>
        <display-name>CBS</display-name>
        <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201.s3. ... w_270h.png"/>
    </channel>
    <channel id="EPG123.11331.schedulesdirect.org">
        <display-name>WCBS</display-name>
        <display-name>2 WCBS</display-name>
        <display-name>2</display-name>
        <display-name>CBS</display-name>
        <icon src="https://schedulesdirect-api20141201.s3. ... w_270h.png"/>
    </channel>
</tv>';

--INSERT INTO channels (...)
SELECT
      c.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(50)') id,
      c.value('(display-name/text())[1]','varchar(50)') chan1,
      c.value('(display-name[sql:column("seq.pos") - 3]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') chan2,
      c.value('(display-name[sql:column("seq.pos") - 2]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') chan3 ,
      c.value('(display-name[sql:column("seq.pos") - 1]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') chan4,
      c.value('(display-name[sql:column("seq.pos")]/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') chan5,
      c.value('(icon/@src)[1]','varchar(100)') icon
      --, seq.pos
FROM @xml.nodes('/tv/channel') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.c.value('count(./display-name)','INT') AS pos
         ) AS seq;
```

**Output**

```
+----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                id                | chan1 | chan2 | chan3  | chan4 | chan5 |                          icon                          |
+----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| EPG123.11331.schedulesdirect.org | WCBS  | WCBS  | 2 WCBS |     2 | CBS   | https://schedulesdirect-api20141201.s3. ... w_270h.png |
| EPG123.11331.schedulesdirect.org | WCBS  | WCBS  | 2 WCBS |     2 | CBS   | https://schedulesdirect-api20141201.s3. ... w_270h.png |
+----------------------------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yithak & Charlie, I got the code to work with your expert help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`OPENXML` has been somewhat deprecated in favour of XQuery functions such as `.nodes()` and `.value()`.

In this example, I have used the variable directly in the `FROM`. If you have an XML table column, you should use `CROSS APPLY`.

`.nodes` breaks out the XML into rows, the example you gave does not have `tv` as the root node.

`.value` requires a single value result, best practice is to enclose the whole XQuery in brackets, followed by `[1]` to get the first node.

`text()` gets you the actual value of a node, you don't technically need this, but it performs faster.

`@` is short-hand to refer to an attribute.

`..` is short-hand to refer to the immediate parent node.

We use the predicate `[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then ...` to get the particular node we want, we still need `[1]` because it is not a constant expression.

```sql
SELECT
      channel.value('(@id)[1]', 'varchar(50)') id,
      channel.value('(display-name/text())[1]','varchar(50)') chan1,
      channel.value('(display-name[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then 1 else 2)]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') chan2,
      channel.value('(display-name[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then 2 else 3)]/text())[1]','varchar(50)') chan3 ,
      channel.value('(display-name[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then 3 else 4)]/text())[1]','float') chan4,
      channel.value('(display-name[(if(count(../display-name) = 4) then 4 else 5)]/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') chan5,
      channel.value('(icon/@src)[1]','varchar(100)') icon
INTO channels
FROM @hdoc.nodes('/channel') x(channel)
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution.  However I get a syntax error on the INTO clause.  I've tried on both SQL Server 2014 and 2019.  I'm trying to figure it out, but I won't turn down any help.  I added the full code in the original post.